# "Uncaught TypeError: posts.map is not a function" , How to solve this error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, json, drupal-9

So I was fetching data from my local drupal instance in react js. I pass the data from drupal with json api module (Which send the data in json format).
The following image is the data in form of json api.[image]

And following is how i am fetching the api and mapping it in on front end.

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Slider from "react-slick";

function Homeslidersection() {
  const settings = {
    dots: false,
    arrows: false,
    infinite: true,
    speed: 500,
    autoplay: false,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
  };
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    async function loadPosts() {
      const response = await fetch(
        "http://localhost/drupalreact/jsonapi/node/banner?include=field_banner_image"
      );
      if (!response.ok) {
        // oups! something went wrong
        return;
      }
      const posts = await response.json();
      setPosts(posts);
    }
    loadPosts();
  }, []);
  return (
    <>
      <div className="home-slider-section">
        <div className="homesliderwrapper">
          <div className="home-slider-folder">
            <Slider {...settings}>
            {posts.map((post,index) => (
              <div className="home-slider-blog-box-section">
                <div className="home-slider-image">
                  <img src="" />
                </div>
                <div className="home-slider-text-folder1">
                  <h2>Looking</h2>
                  <span>Flexible Workspace In Your City!</span>
                  <p>
                    Our global network of workspaces enable you to work wherever
                    you need to be.
                  </p>
                  <a href="#" className="Read-More">
                    Read More
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
              ))}
            </Slider>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default Homeslidersection;
```

I know the error **Uncaught TypeError: posts.map is not a function** is due my data coming from drupal json api is not in array format.

Like if see the image, the whole data is `{[]}` not in array `[...]` format

How do i solve this error? Because i cannot change anything from my drupal end, so how can solve this error from my front end code in react js?

Answer (score 2):

data is inside the `data` property.

```
  setPosts(posts.data);
```

Comment: Thanks buddy i tried this , but now {posts.data.map((post,index) => ())} if i use it like this is still give one error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')"? can you help me with this also please?

Answer (score 2):

As the data received from the API is having multiple properties (`jsonapi`, `data`), and you are storing the whole response in your state, that's why it was throwing the error.

Two solutions:

- Either only store the `data` array in your state (`setPosts(posts.data)`)
- Or, if you want to use `jsonapi` object somewhere, you can change your map function (`posts.data.map(...)`)

Comment: Thanks buddy i tried this , but now {posts.data.map((post,index) => ())} if i use it like this is still give one error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')"? can you help me with this also please?

Answer (score 1):

One reason is actual data is in response.data, so you should setState(response.data) as explained in above answer.
The second reason is your posts is empty because setState() is asynchronous. It means the posts in jsx runs before posts is populated with data.
You can solve it by using two ways.
1). Conditional rendering

```
 { posts.length && posts.map(----)}
```

2). Null Check(just put ? before .map)

```
posts?.map(--)
```

Comment: Thanks buddy i tried this , but now {posts.data.map((post,index) => ())} if i use it like this is still give one error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')"? can you help me with this also please?

Comment: @Mohammad Muazam try this. {posts?.data?.map((post,index) => () )}. If it solves your problem, then for details see the above answer, if not please share the code/screen shot